# value does not get assigned to variable in class

Tags: c++

i have been trying to read `weaponAttack` using `float x` as a public value for `readItem` but `x` reads as 0

some code from header containing classes

```
 class item
    {
    private:
        string name;
        string description;
        int price;
    public:
        void readItem(float x);
        item(string n, string desc, int p);
    };

    class weapon : public item
    {
    private:
        float weaponAttack;
    public:
        weapon(string n, string desc, int p, float attack) : item(n, desc, p) { weaponAttack = attack; };
        float x = weaponAttack;
    };
```

source.cpp containing values for class

```
weapon Weapon("Sword", "Description", 200, 10.0f); // 10.f does not get assigned to x
Weapon.readItem(Weapon.x);//used to check if values are correct
```

Comment: Just because you wrote `int a; int b = a;`, doesn't mean that when you `a = 10;`, that `b` changes. In your case, you never change `x`, so no wonder its undefined.

Comment: Search terms: "value semantics" and "references".

Comment: @Rakete1111 wow another case of me being retarded and the answer being in front of my nose again `weapon(string n, string desc, int p, float attack) : item(n, desc, p) { weaponAttack = attack; x = weaponAttack; };` fixed the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigment in declaration means that you want to set a default initialization value to the member variable at construction, in case the constructor does not initialize such member variable. So when you construct your *weapon* object, *x* is initialized with *weaponAttack* before *weaponAttack* (which is already initialized with no value) is assigned with the value of *attack*.

The right way to do it is by assigning the value of *weaponAttack* to *x* in the scope of the constructor or, even better, by also initializing the variable *x* in the constructor right after the initialization *weaponAttack* (C++ ensures initialization order).

And in case you want *x* and *weaponAttack* to always have the same value without hurting the encapsulation of *weaponAttack*, you should use *x* as a constant reference to it. This will allow you to publicly access *x* although its value will only change when *weaponAttack* is privately modified.

So the final result should be:

```
class weapon: public item
{
    float weaponAttack;
    
    public:
    
    float const & x;
    
    weapon(std::string n, std::string desc, int p, float attack)
    : item(n, desc, p), weaponAttack(attack), x(weaponAttack)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: well this explanation was quite nice, have been using that x variable only for reading the weaponAttack in readitem function since i cant pass it in there without having public value to use

Comment: Glad to help! =] I also like the "const reference" solution, but keep in mind that OOP guidelines usually advocates for the extensive use of gets and sets instead of public access of member variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're assigning to `weaponAttack` instead of initialising it. If you initialise it in the constructor's mem-initialiser list, the in-class initialiser of `x` (which is declared and this unitiliased later than `weaponAttack`) will use it:

```
weapon(string n, string desc, int p, float attack) : item(n, desc, p), weaponAttack(attack) {};
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5163946bce6484d)

This is just one of several reasons why you should always use the mem-initialiser list if possible instead of doing assignments in constructor body.